# Prove the linearity of the following maps

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-fields

Let $f,g$ and $h$ be in $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is the following statement true?

*If $x^2+y^2+z^2=(f(x,y,z))^2+(g(x,y,z))^2+(h(x,y,z))^2$ then $F=(f,g,h)$ is linear*

Maybe this could be a consecuence for some conformal map theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 3$? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should specify that f,g, and h are real valued. Otherwise it is false.

Comment: Suppose also that $f,g$ and $h$ are real valued. How could be the proof? I can write it

Comment: On the other hand, it is true that if $$(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2 = (f(x,y,z) - f(x',y',z'))^2 + (g(x,y,z) - g(x',y',z'))^2 + (h(x,y,z) - h(x',y',z'))^2$$
for all $x,y,z,x',y',z'$ and $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0,0)=h(0,0,0)=0$ then $F$ is linear.

Answer (score 4):

No. For example, let $$f(x,y,z)=x\sin z-y\cos z$$$$g(x,y,z)=x\cos z+y\sin z$$ $$h(x,y,z)=z$$
Then, $F(1,1,\frac{\pi}{4})=(0,\sqrt2,\frac\pi4)$ and $F(2,2,\pi/2)=(2,2,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Hence $F(2,2,\frac{\pi}{2}) \neq2F(1,1,\frac{\pi}{4})$, which contradicts linearity of $F$.

Comment: You need to remove the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in $f$ and $g$

Comment: Oh yes, thanks :)

Comment: Don't forget to update the function values.